# GitPython get all commits in range between start sha1 and end sha1

Tags: python, gitpython

I am using the [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library and was wondering how to get all commits on a branch in range of two commit sha-1's. I have the start one and end one. Is there any way to get list of them?

I have instantiated the repo object and was wondering if there was a way to query it and obtain a list of commits in the range of two shas?

Would be looking to do something similar to this command but return them as a list:

```
git log e0d8a4c3fec7ef2c352342c2ffada21fa07c1dc..63af686e626e0a5cbb0508367983765154e188ce --pretty=format:%h,%an,%s > commits.csv
```

Seems like there is [Repo.iter_commits()](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.iter_commits) method but can't see how to specify a range.

Comment: Hey updated the answer with my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `repo.iter_commits("revA..revB")`

@rtn's answer has the solution, but it's a little hidden. Here's a minimal example for ease of understanding.

```py
from git import Repo

repo = Repo("/path/to/your/repo")
start_rev, end_rev = "HEAD~2", "HEAD"  # Or any other valid ref

commits = repo.iter_commits(f"{start_rev}..{end_rev}")

for commit in commits:
  # Do your thing...
```

`start_rev` and `end_rev` can be a git commit hash, branch name, or tag name -- i.e. anything supported by [`git log A..B`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_description)

---

From the [docs for `Repo.iter_commits`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.iter_commits:%7E:text=to%20receive%20only%20commits%20between%20two%20named%20revisions%2C%20use%20the%20%E2%80%9Creva...revb%E2%80%9D%20revision%20specifier):

> to receive only commits between two named revisions, use the “revA…revB” revision specifier

Answer (score 2):

@shlomi33 here was my solution:

This is the method that I used to set a List of GitPyhton Commit Object. Within the class I have already instantiated the Repo object which this method relies on.

Edit: have also added the init method that is used to set up the Repo object instance.

```
def __init__(self, repo_url, project_name, branch_name) -> None:
    """
    Clone the required repo in the repo folder and instantiate the Repo instance
    :param repo_url: str of the git repository url
    :param project_name: str of the project name
    :param branch_name: str of the branch name
    """
    self._repo_url = repo_url
    self._project = project_name
    self._branch = branch_name
    self._project_dir = Path(self._repo_dir, self._project)

    if self._project_dir.exists():
        self._logger.info('Deleting existing repo: ' + str(self._project_dir))
        shutil.rmtree(self._project_dir)

    self._logger.info('Creating directory for repo: ' + str(self._project_dir))
    os.makedirs(self._project_dir)

    try:
        self.repo = GitRepo.clone_from(self._repo_url, self._project_dir, branch=self._branch,
                                       progress=self.__progress)
    except GitCommandError:
        self._logger.error('Failed to clone repo. Make sure you have git ssh access set up.')
        raise
    self._logger.info('Repository downloaded to: ' + str(self._repo_dir))

def set_commits(self, start_rev: str, end_rev: str):
    """
    Sets a list of Commits for the range of the start rev and end rev
    :param start_rev: Start commit revision SHA1
    :param end_rev: End commit revision
    """
    self._start_rev = start_rev
    self._end_rev = end_rev
    commits = self.repo.iter_commits(start_rev + '..' + end_rev)
    self._commits = list(map(Commit, list(commits)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a efficient or elegant solution, but very short:

Iterate over commits from branch HEAD until specific commit was reached.

```py
other_commit = repo.commit(commit_sha)

commits = []
for commit in repo.iter_commits():
    if commit == other_commit:
        break
    commits.append(commit)
```

This was fine for my usecase.