# How do I get a list of gerrit commits between start and end SHA1 without cloning the project

Tags: git, gerrit

I am trying to find a way to get a list of `Gerrit` commits between given start commit SHA to end commit SHA **without cloning the repository.**

I tried the following `Gerrit` query:

```
ssh -p 29418 my.gerrit.address gerrit query --format=JSON project:my-project <start-sha>..<end-sha>
```

But instead of getting a list of commits, I get the following response:

```
{"type":"stats","rowCount":0,"runTimeMilliseconds":5,"moreChanges":false}
```

There is the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668241/gitpython-get-all-commits-in-range-between-start-sha1-and-end-sha1) but unfortunately it requires cloning.

Comment: The man page for [`gerrit query`](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html) states `Query the change search index` - so it's not going to give you commits, unless they are open reviews. As far as I know , you can't do what you want without cloning the repository.

Comment: Gerrit does not have such a feature to meet your needs. In our case, we maintain a group of mirror repositories that are constantly synced with the Gerrit repositories. A Django server is running on the machine. It retrieves commits in the mirror repositories and send them back to the client user on request, so that the user does not have to clone the repository.